# how to maintain records current as well as previous in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi any one please help i have a contact table in which i can Insert,Delete,Modify database using PHP web pages....but only current changes will be updated to database. what i want is how i can maintain history of database...
  Is there any tutorial for this using (PHP/MYSQL).
I tried creating version of MySQL table for patient... how to proceed further.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contact` (
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `conid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`conid`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ; # MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contactversion` (
   `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   `phone` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
   `mobile` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
   `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   `address` text NOT NULL,
   `conid` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `revision_id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type ENUM('INSERT', 'UPDATE', 'DELETE') NOT NULL,
   `change_time` DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (`revision_id`)
 );
```

what to do next....

Answer (score 0):

When running the queries to contact, just simply run this right before to take the current contact and copy it in your revision table...

```
"INSERT INTO 
    contactversion (name,phone,mobile,email,address,conid,type) 
    SELECT 
        name,phone,mobile,email,address,conid,'".$type."' as type 
    FROM contact 
    WHERE conid='".$conid."'"
```

Both tables will require to be identical, with contactversion having type and change_time as additionnal last columns.

It is obvious that this query should be ran before UPDATE and DELETE of the contact table, but after an INSERT. If you are updating multiple contacts with another where clause than the conid, you'll want to consider building the where statement in a variable to use it inside the INSERT's SELECT and the UPDATE/DELETE

Comment: Thanks for response...Is there any mistake in my contactversion table?is there any example for this...

Comment: my database contactversion is not updating after i used the Insert command.

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken with the insert from a select statement. This should be fixed now.

Comment: giving sysntax error in the query Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER ...

Comment: Trying to be too fast... Sorry, this should fix it?

Answer (score -1):

While creating contactversions table make sure conid should not be primary key and auto incremented. I hope that is causing the problem.